# C++ assigning a new address to *next in a data structure

Tags: c++, pointers, data-structures, struct

there's something I can't get my head round...
Basically I'm given the following data structure:

```
struct node_ll {
    int payload;
    node_ll *next;  //pointer to next node
};
```

Which is essentially a stack of numbers.
I need to create a method with the following prototype:

```
int tail_return(node_ll **list)
```

where `**list` is the memory address of the above data structure. My implementation is as follows:

```
int tail_return(node_ll **list) {

    node_ll *temp;
    temp = *list;

    node_ll *prev_temp;
    prev_temp = *list;

    bool firstPass = true;

    while(temp){

        if(firstPass == true){
        temp = temp->next;
        firstPass = false;

        } else {
            temp = temp->next;
            prev_temp = prev_temp->next;

        }
    }

    int toReturn = prev_temp->payload;

    prev_temp->payload = 0;
    (**list).next = prev_temp;

    delete temp;
    delete prev_temp;
    return toReturn;
}
```

However I get the following output from test runs:

```
List a after head insertion of 2,4,6,8,10 elements:

{10,8,6,4,2}

now removing the last element

DELETED: 2

{10,0} where it's supposed to be: {10,8,6,4}
```

What am I doing wrong? Apparently the method finds the right value to delete - 2. But why when I try to print it after deletion I end up with 10 and 0?

Comment: What is `tail` return supposed to do?

Comment: Think about what this line of code does: `(**list).next = prev_temp;`

Comment: You should use `std::list` or `std::stack`, available respectively from `<list>` and `<stack>`.

Comment: tail_return finds the last element in this stack, returns it and deletes it. For example - I have another method head_return which returns the first element and deletes it and it works fine.
(**list).next = prev_temp; I wa under the impression this should access the *next in the node_ll and set it to the address held in prev_temp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 (**list).next = prev_temp;
```

should be

```
prev_temp->next = 0 ;
```

when you do `(**list).next = prev_temp;` you are manipulating the parameter which was passed to your method and not the last node in the linked list.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that tail_return is supposed to take a linked list of node_ll 's and delete the tail element?

Yes per @Aditya , looks like the

```
(**list).next = prev_temp;
```

line is causing a problem. The reason is that you are reassigning list to point to the second to last element (prev_temp).

Deleting the last element is correctly done by

```
delete temp;
```

And also remove the line

```
delete prev_temp;
```

since that removes the second to last element too, which you want to keep.

Plus you are currently returning the second to last element. So change

```
int toReturn = prev_temp->payload;
```

to

```
int toReturn = temp->payload;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(**list).next = prev_temp;
```

is too complicated. If you write it like this

```
(*list)->next = prev_temp;
```

it now becomes clear(er) that you change the **first** element in the list.

This is just a small recommendation for writing clearer code. See the other answers for the solutions to your problem(s).